# Struct and object oriented in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I come from C, C++, Java background. I want to create a struct/ class with some attributes and methods like:

```
MyClass{
    string text;
    array characters;
    printText(){ 
       print text;
    }
    printLen(){
       print characters.length();
    }
}
```

So next time I can create an object like above by just calling its constructor. How do I implement this in JavaScript? I am new to the programming principles followed in javascript, I want to create a custom data type here for reusability.

Comment: Have you searched for anything yet? This is one of the most common questions. It is really simple. Good luck!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript or just look for related questions is SO

Comment: Great reference about javascript patterns: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ take a look at Constructor Pattern. Also, Module and Singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function MyClass () {
    this.text = "";
    this.characters = [];
}

MyClass.prototype.printText = function () {
    console.log(this.text);
};

MyClass.prototype.printLen = function () {
    console.log(this.characters.length);
};

var instance = new MyClass();
instance.text = "test";
instance.characters.push('a');
instance.characters.push('b');
instance.printText();
instance.printLen();
```

Comment: `this.characters.length` rather than `this.characters.lengt` Moreover, we don't know whathe means by "print".

Comment: It is just an example.

Comment: I want to create a javascript library where I define such contructs. Is this a good way in such a context?

Comment: You must to declare your library in one file and include it using a HTML SCRIPT tag. `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/library.js"></script>`

Comment: I meant is it a good design principle?

Comment: Yes, it is. Doing this you can reuse your library and Classes.